# Swift Playground add a WORKING image view

Tags: swift, image

All I want to do is add an image to the centre of my view in Swift Playgrounds. I have tried every solution on the internet in which none of them works. Where do I put my image file? What do I code to actually display it?

Here is an example of code that doesn't work:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "egg.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Are you talking about playground that you’re running in Xcode or on iOS device? If the latter, see [Playground Book Format](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/swift_playgrounds_doc_format/index.html).

Comment: I am coding on Xocde on a Mac and I have added an example of code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You drag it into the Resources folder, then access it from the Bundle.  Sample code:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 916, height: 611))
view.backgroundColor = .white
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 916, height: 611))
view.addSubview(imageView)


if let sample = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "jpg") {
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: sample)
    imageView.image = image
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView
```

Here's the result:

[image: playground result]

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure your images are in the Resources Folder. Access these by clicking Command + 1.